# Node.js write raw image data

Tags: node.js, ansi

I'm writing a node.js server, and for part of the site, the user needs to be able to upload an image. When an image is uploaded, it's copy on the server is corrupt.

Here's the script for the body parser.

```
request.body = {};
var busboy = new Busboy({headers: request.headers});
busboy.on("field", function(fieldname, val) {
  request.body[fieldname] = val;
});
busboy.on("file", function(fieldname, file, filename) {
  var fileContents = "";
  file.on("data", function(data) {
    fileContents += data;
  });
  file.on("end", function() {
    request.body[fieldname] = {"filename": filename, "contents": fileContents};
  });
});
busboy.on("finish", function() {
  next(request, response);
});
request.pipe(busboy);
```

When a text file is uploaded, the server saves it just fine, but certain symbols in image files aren't sent or received correctly.

Comment: Write the file in ANSI? What? An image file is binary data, which doesn't really depend on your choice of encoding. What lead you to identifying this as the problem? Have you had a look at the 'corrupted' file, checked if it contained HTTP headers or some garbage data?

Comment: Without some code it's hard to tell what going on.

Comment: Well the file that I'm uploading has characters like ‰, but when node.js writes them to a file, they become �. So is there a different way for me to keep the characters when writing the file?

Comment: That's because `data` is a [`Buffer`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) and by default, when you treat it like a string (by appending it to another string), the encoding is UTF8. The solution is don't treat it like a string, treat it like a buffer, then you won't end up with malformed code points.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts That sounds like an answer IMO … Also, Nicholas, how is the file uploaded? I mean the HTML form – does it have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` ?

Comment: @AurelBílý I didn't feel like posting it as an answer because I didn't want the responsibility of elaborating what I meant with example code. If anyone else wants to copy-pasta my comment as an answer and elaborate, feel free.

Comment: Yes the form has enctype="multipart/form-data", thanks @PatrickRoberts, I'll try implementing that right now.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickRoberts I stored the buffer instead of the string, and concated them all, then wrote the buffer to a file and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

> That's because data is a Buffer and by default, when you treat it like a string (by appending it to another string), the encoding is UTF8. The solution is don't treat it like a string, treat it like a buffer, then you won't end up with malformed code points. – Patrick Roberts

As Patrick said, the problem was in `fileContents += data;`. This converts the `data` buffer to a string, which can't contain the characters I needed. Instead, I added each data buffer to an array, then concatenated them all, and wrote that to a file.